# setting global paragraph style with phpword

Tags: php, phpword

I'm using PHPWord and would like to set the spaceAfter paragraph style to 0 for every paragraph. Unfortunately, I'm unaware of how to do this globally. You can set the font size / name globally by doing this:

```
$phpWord->setDefaultFontName('Times New Roman');
$phpWord->setDefaultFontSize(12);
```

But how might I set the spaceAfter default paragraph style?

Per http://phpword.readthedocs.org/en/latest/elements.html#paragraph-style I can also set it every time I call `addText()` (by setting the third  parameter) but that could get old, fast.

Setting it globally would be the ideal approach.

I'm using Beta 0.6.3.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Beta 0.6.3 version (in CodePlex) is an old inactive project - there is a new active version (that is based on that CodePlex project) in GitHub that you can find here [PhpWord: GitHub](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord)

And with the new project version (no idea if this applicable in the old 0.6.3 as well), you can set the default paragraph style like this (copied from Sample_08_ParagraphPagination.php):

```
$phpWord->setDefaultParagraphStyle(
    array(
        'align'      => 'both',
        'spaceAfter' => \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Converter::pointToTwip(12),
        'spacing'    => 120,
        )
    );
```